# Is it better to use temporary variables in place of repeated full references?

Tags: javascript, performance, object

Say we have an object something like:

```
var foo = { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { f: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] } } } } } };
```

And we want to use the various parts of the object in functions along the lines of:

```
function doStuff() {
    if ( foo.a.b.c.d.e.f[ 5 ] >= some_important_filter_value ) {
        alert( "Some important filter value is " + foo.a.b.c.d.e.f[ 5 ] +
            "!!\nRun for your lives!!" );
    }
}
```

And for argument's sake, the values contained within `foo` aren't going to be changing during the course of the function execution, or for that matter, very often at all.

**Is it *better* to read the values from the object and store them as temporary variables/constants, or perfectly fine to use the full path through the object `foo` as the reference for the value?**

*i.e.* Is

```
function doStuff() {
    var mem = foo.a.b.c.d.e.f[ 5 ];
    if ( mem >= some_important_filter_value ) {
        alert( "Some important filter value is " + mem +
            "!!\nRun for your lives!!" );
    }
}
```

*"better"*, and if so, in exactly what way(s)?

**My own limited testing** in Google Chrome's JS console shows `100000` while loops deeply querying an object, against the same number of loops querying a temporary variable to run at approximately the same speed.

Effectively copying and storing a value from `foo` into a temporary variable for use any number of times, may in certain circumstances have a practical value insofar that code/file size may be reduced and readability *may be* improved, but leaving that aside for the purposes of this question, what other arguments in its favour can be made?

The creation and handling of a temporary var is surely less trivial for modern JS interpreters than simply referencing the value within the object directly?

**Why and how would `var temp = foo.a.b.c...` be *better* than skipping the definition and just using the value via the reference we already have?**

I suppose that fundamentally what I'm asking is - does it really matter how many dots there are in my reference, since in the long run, it's just a reference - or is it?

Comment: *"does it really matter how many dots there are in my reference, since in the long run, it's just a reference"* Nope. At some level one way will be more *"effiecient"* than the other, but in the end the difference in execution will be so small that it's irrelevant.

Comment: seems like readability and code maintenance is another factor

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it unless and until you profile your code and find it to be a bottleneck. Readability, on the other hand, is a much bigger issue and for that reason copying `foo.a.b.c...` into a temporary variable is probably a good idea when you are going to refer to it more than once. It also makes it harder to accidentally mistype and access `foo.a.b.c` one time and `foo.a.c.b` the next time.

Comment: @charlietfl True and agreed, but for the sake of this question, can we assume that readability, code /file size etc. is irrelevant? I'd like to focus purely on the efficiency - the mechanics if you will - of the code this time. Cheers. I've edited the question in response.

Comment: "My own limited testing": You might also try [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) if you are curious.

Comment: @KevinB Would you care to expand your comment as an answer with references and stuff? "Nope" may be right, but might also just be an opinion; one I hope is true BTW :-)

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks for the link. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Here's a test I set up: http://jsperf.com/temp-vs-dot, pretty much no difference.

Comment: @MattBurland Indeed. That looks a lot like my own tests. And dots win by a whisker (sometimes). However, speed is perhaps only one aspect of the performance variables we should consider. Memory allocation, framerates and stuff like that are also really rather important. However this comments section is already a conversation, and ideally a well formed answer would be appreciated in place of (albeit pleasant) chatter.

Comment: @FredGandt "Nope", because i find it to be a waste of time. Feel free to test it yourself though with jsperf and the profiler in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the wonderful realm of pedantry, you are going to pay the penalty of resolving those references, time and again.

If these were "classes" (constructed objects, which might be referencing values on the **proto** chain), then you pay the added penalty of failing to find the value on the object, and ascending the **proto** chain until you do (or hit Object.prototype, still miss the property, and throw a reference error, when you try to access a property of that missing object).

Now, all told, if that added even 1ms in your stress tests of modern engines, I would be flabbergasted.

Chrome's V8 will go a long way to recompile code on the fly, which includes things like unwinding loops, inlining functions, et cetera; so long as you use functions consistently (passing similar arguments/argument-types), every time.

There were some good talks on this stuff, relating to writing game engines in Chrome, circa 2012, I believe.

The moral is that most of what you do, if done more than a couple of times, will just be compiled down to an inline operation...

...in a new browser...

You would take a performance hit the moment you did something like

```
if (i % 3001) { a.b.e.f.g[6]; }
else { a.b.c.d.e.f[5]; }
```

...again, that's modern engines.

If you were to run your load test on a 2003 Windows XP system, running IE6, your numbers should be different, due to the aforementioned reasons.

They shouldn't be hundreds of ms off...
They should, however, reflect the performance hit of dereferencing values multiple times, and that performance penalty should increase if the properties are **proto** linked, and increase again based on the distance up the chain to resolve each property.

To wit, I'm referring to the browsers where tests of `a.b.c` versus `a["b"]["c"]` were perceivably different.

Comment: This does rather boil down to "mistakes hurt more ...", but mistakes always hurt, and yes, it is the efficiency of modern compilers/interpreters that led me to ask the question in the first place. If this were the early noughties, I would have no doubt that local/temporary variables were "ideal", but it's the future now, and reams of throwaway vars everywhere seem utterly unnecessary. I continue to wonder if there's more to it than meets the eye.

Comment: @FredGandt: Compilers optimizing away your overhead are no excuse of writing bad code. In this particular case, repeating that lenghty property access is just not DRY.

Comment: @FredGandt if you read it again, you should note that it's not a "mistake", but a feature of the language, to climb the __proto__ chain.  Moreover, it's not a question of making a "mistake" in tripping up the compiled code; passing a number, versus passing a string representation of a number, or passing an object instance of a particular type, and then passing in an instance of a different type, or passing in an instance where properties have been added or deleted from outside of the constructor can all cause a de-op.  These de-ops have a larger impact than dereferencing, now.

Comment: @Bergi I am asking this question to establish what is "bad" code. I personally take great pains to optimise my own code, and the fact that I take the time to ask this question should show that to be the case. I'm not making any excuses. As for "repeating myself", a repeated reference is often unavoidable, and the whole point of the question is to establish if one reference method is really any worse, better or even practically different than another.

Comment: If you want the low-level answer (circa ~2012) as to whether or not there's a difference, I'd argue that it's all right here (in a very basic format, without going into how Chrome allocates memory for objects, predefined, versus dynamic, versus large-dictionary), without getting someone like Colt McAnlis in here to talk micro-op in 2014-2015.

Comment: But really, it boils down to "quit trying to outsmart the compiler, and let it do its job". If you want to unwind your loops by hand, that will be a bigger performance increase in various engines, than aliasing objects, if you really care about every single instruction, on every single clock.

Comment: @Norguard I'm not trying to "outsmart the compiler", and frankly that tone isn't helpful. Caring about (evolving) best practice, and wishing to have a deeper understanding of the processes behind the results in an effort to write better code is all I'm interested in. I appreciate your answer, and it's a good point.

Comment: @FredGandt Sorry, I didn't mean it to come off as a tone; it's a mantra; one that Google's Chrome team has used on more than a few occasions, through the recent years.  I'll see if I can't dig out the videos I'm referring to, though I can't remember which year and conference they were (certainly in the last 5).  The talks focussed on making actual high-performance HTML5 canvas-based games, as such, the object-pushing, memory and loop-management advice were much more pertinent than for typical web stuff (which is nearly 60+fps on JS-enabled toasters, these days, with careful DOM access).

Comment: @Norguard Ah, sry too then :-) I'll be interested to see the links if you can find them. Possibly anything to do with Udacity?

Answer (score 1):

As you yourself tested it, and as confirmed by Matt Burland above, nested object references are not meaningfully different in performance to copied references.

The thing you want to watch for in terms of performance is function calls. If you have foo.a().b().c()... instead, the function calls themselves start to become expensive. Here the difference becomes pronounced, as shown in my little revision of Matt's jsperf test: http://jsperf.com/temp-vs-dot/2

Comment: Good point. I must admit, I expected a greater difference in performance than I saw. However, even the small performance hit could be important in some cases. Definitely worth keeping in mind.